# Possible to have fine-grained horizontal Auto Layout control in vertical UIStackView?

Tags: ios, autolayout, uikit, uistackview

I'm currently working with a vertical `UIStackView` in which each view has a `UILabel` to be displayed on the left and a `UIButton` to be displayed on the right.  The leading constraint for the label should be different than the trailing constraint for the button and the entire view should take up the width of the screen.  The `alignment` for the stackview is `fill` and the distribution is `fillEqually`.

[image]

The problem I'm running into is that Auto Layout doesn't seem to be respecting the trailing constraint that I'm trying to set for the button on `fill` alignment (or any other alignment, for that matter).  No matter what I put for it, the system sets it to `20`.  I've tried `center`, `leading`, and `trailing` alignments but they don't work for what I'm trying to do.  Is it possible to have the degree of horizontal layout control I'd like with a vertical stackview?

My constraints (`radioButton` trailing constraint constant is set to `0`):

```
private func sharedInitialization() {
    translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    textLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    radioButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    addSubview(textLabel)
    addSubview(radioButton)

    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        radioButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30),
        radioButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30),
        radioButton.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor, constant: 0),
        radioButton.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerYAnchor),
        textLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: radioButton.leadingAnchor, constant: -10),
        textLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor, constant: 22),
        textLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: 10),
        bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: textLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: 22)])
}
```

Visual debugger:
[image]

I've looked at [Prevent vertical UIStackView from stretching a subview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52650210/prevent-vertical-uistackview-from-stretching-a-subview) but that doesn't seem quite applicable to my situation.  Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Are your label and button embedded in a `UIView`?

Comment: Yes, they are—the code I posted is their constraint setup in that view.

Comment: Are you running some other code that could be modifying the constraints? this is what I get using your code: https://imgur.com/a/28GToMX

Comment: Durr, stackview had a trailing constraint constant.  Should've gotten another set of eyes on it first.  Thanks for the help!